# How to print iterate over HashMap and Print Values

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I am currently trying to Print A selected Word from my HashMap to screen.The output correct the first time, however each time after it gives the first value, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
public void searchIndex() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a word to search");
        String entry = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        String key = null;
        String value = null;
        Set<Integer> indices = null;
        for (String search : index.keySet()) {
            for (WordEntry values : index.values()) {

                key = search;
                value = values.getDefinition();
                indices = values.getIndices();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Word " + key + " And " + value + indices);
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue searching,'Yes' if so");
        String answer = sc.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            searchIndex();
```

Output:
Please Enter a word to search

yellow

Word yellow And color

Do you wish to continue searching,'Yes' if so

yes

Please Enter a word to search

open

Word yellow And color

Do you wish to continue searching,'Yes' if so

Comment: Share sample input and output, and expected output

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen, but it seems you're never using the input you get from the user - `entry` is never used.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to search for a word in the hashmap, The first time it gives a the value, then when i continue searching i select another word, but it returns the first value

Answer (score 0):

In this block:

```
for (String search : index.keySet()) {
    for (WordEntry values : index.values()) {
       key = search;
       value = values.getDefinition();
       indices = values.getIndices();
    }
}
```

You are setting the values of `key`, `value`, and `indices` **unconditionally**.

This means that whatever your input is, it will always set :

- `key` to the last key in `index`.
- `value` to the  definition of the last value in `index`.
- And `indices` to the last indices of the last value in `index`.

And, I guess that Yellow is the last item in `index`. Hence you get the said output.

I think you need to set the values of `key`, `value`, and `indices` according to some condition based on the input.